# common lisp - get path to file

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

In Common Lisp, is there a way to get the path to a compiled file (something like current-directory)?

The file is not inside the current-directory folder.

Answer (score 14):

This ought to be a comment but I'm going to give some code examples that might help the original poster along.

First of all, you need to be a little more clear about what you want to do.  What is the problem you're trying to solve?

Secondly, here are a couple of examples which could be useful:

- [`*default-pathname-defaults*`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/v_defaul.htm) usually set to the directory the CL image was started up in:

  ```
  * *default-pathname-defaults*
  #P"/Users/aerique/"
  ```
- [`merge-pathnames`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_merge_.htm#merge-pathnames) allows you to construct new pathnames:

  ```
  * (merge-pathnames "lib/misc" *default-pathname-defaults*)
  #P"/Users/aerique/lib/misc"
  * (merge-pathnames "lib/misc/" *default-pathname-defaults*)
  #P"/Users/aerique/lib/misc/"
  ```
- `asdf:system-source-directory` returns the path to a system loaded with [ASDF](http://common-lisp.net/project/asdf/asdf/Miscellaneous-additional-functionality.html):

  ```
  * (asdf:system-source-directory :linedit)  
  #P"/Users/aerique/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/linedit-20111203-git/"
  ```

Also see the linked ASDF manual for more useful file and system functions.

Answer (score 9):

`*load-truename*` resp. `*load-pathname*` gives you what you need.

http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/v_ld_pns.htm

Answer (score 2):

Perchance you want `compile-file-pathname`, which gives you the destination where `compile-file` would write into.

It'd help if you provide more context on what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

If you want get the pathname whitout use ASDF function, but you need also attend the users that use ASDF, you can use like this:

```
(defmacro project-pathname ()
  (let ((path (or *compile-file-pathname* *load-truename*)))
    `(progn ,path)))
```

It's necessary because the ASDF stores in one "*/home/you/.../.cache/...*" directory, and you need capture the pathname in compilation time with one macro.

Answer (score -2):

You can use:

```
*default-pathname-defaults*
```

Please see http://cybertiggyr.com/gene/pathnames-0/node11.html